# Save Notes Info in (txt) file with Infos

Tags: java, save

So i did a notes app with some infos about the note:

```
private String text;
private String date;
private String time;
```

I saved them in a txt file and added a regex Pattern so i can sort them out later:

```
String array[] = scan.nextLine().split(Pattern.quote("#§END$#"));
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
                {

                    note = array[0];
                    text = array[1];
                    date = array[2];
                    time = array[3];
                    panel.updateUI();
```

But now i want to know if there are some better ways to save them?

Because when i add a text with some new lines and save them i get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: First, don’t call updateUI, is not going what you seem to think it is

Comment: You could write out to a structured format, such as XML or JSON